# Shiny future not worked without any error

Tags: r, shiny, future

There is some problem. When I press a button nothing happens - no error, no warning, no code processing. I get only

```
Timing stopped at: 0.016 0 0.015
```

in shiny log.
Here is code

```
  observeEvent(input$deep_search_button, { 

future({
             deep_search_function(search_name = input$deep_search_req_name_input,
                                  search_request_type = input$select_search_input_type, 
                                  input_search_string = input$deep_search_string_input, 
                                  input_search_matrix = deep_search_matrix_ui, 
                                  search_matrix_processing = input$select_search_matrix_proc, 
                                  deep_search_frame = input$select_search_frame,
                                  user_frame_deep_search = user_def_search_frame, 
                                  use_synonym = input$select_search_synonyms, 
                                  use_processing = input$select_search_text_processing, 
                                  send_email_deep_search = input$deep_search_send_v_email,
                                  receiver_deep_search_email = current_user_email, 
                                  ds_key_topic = input$deep_search_get_dsc_topic , 
                                  ds_make_word_graph = input$deep_search_make_w_graph, 
                                  ds_text_emo_get = input$deep_search_make_emo)
})

})
```

Without future everything works good.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Can you please provide a reproducible example? This will help others help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi. The code is too big (more than 4k lines). There is no way to give an understandable reproducible example. Other user-defined functions that don't use parameters works fine with future. Only this function doesn't work with future. Parameters get from shiny input. Can be it related to function parameters using?